# Best way return an array of the single field from a Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

**SCENARIO:**

Consider a query below

```
SolvedQuestionaire.find({userId : Meteor.userId(), result: 1},{questions: 1});
```

I am just retrieving single field `questions` from all documents in a Collection.

**REQUIREMENT:**

I want to convert it to an array of questions like 
`["capital of India?", "total states in India?" ....]`

I did below code to retrieve the above result, the result has 100k records, it becomes slow.

```
var questions = [];
SolvedQuestionaire.find({userId : Meteor.userId(), result: 1},{questions: 1}).map( 
    function(singleQuestion) {
      questions .push(singleQuestion.question);
    }
);
```

Is there a still a best efficient way to do that?

> NOTE: using latest **Meteor 1.5** and **Mongo 3.2**

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your attempt to solve the problem? What issues are you running into? Asking for **the best efficient way** is merely asking for someone else to write it for you.

Comment: I would have thought [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) would do the trick. What is the problem?

Comment: updated question with existing implementation. i did it with map() but the performance impact is too much :(